# How to set a cookie to expire properly using php

Tags: php, session

I have built a user management system which keeps users logged in for 1 year

I have been able to do this using the below snippet

```
         if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {

          $expire = 365*24*3600; // We choose a one year duration

          ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $expire);

            session_start(); //We start the session 
           // session_regenerate_id(true);
          setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$expire); 
            //Set a session cookies to the one year duration
```

This works as I intended, but then I want to also give users the option to logout and also unset the cookies to expiry.

I am stuck, it doesn't just work my users are trapped and logged in for a whole year as it stands if they needed to logout they wouldn't.

This is what I have tried to unset cookies and clear session variables so that users can be logged out.

```
        if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) )
        setcookie( session_name(), "", time()-31556952, "/" );

         $_SESSION = array();

         session_destroy();

      setcookie('cookie1', '', strtotime('-1 year'));
      setcookie('cookie2', '', strtotime('-1 year'));
```

I am unable to unset the cookie to expire

Please help me.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but `setcookie()` sets `$_COOKIE`, not `$_SESSION`. `$_SESSION` has nothing to do with `$_COOKIE` They are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your user is logged out, you can simply delete the cookie and create a new one that expires after another year.

Try this to delete the cookie, then you can use your code to create a new one:

```
$sessionName = session_name();

if (isset($_COOKIE[$sessionName])) {
  setcookie($sessionName, "", time() - 3600);
}
```

Comment: @Lloyd - Updated the answer, can you test again please, the answer sets the expiration date to one hour ago therefore deletes the cookie